# Are some compiler optimizations invalid in the presence of multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, compiler-construction, language-agnostic, compiler-optimization

For example, imagine we have code like the following, where `d` is a dictionary or other data structure for which indexing is non-trivial:

```
x = d[a]
y = d[b]
z = (x + y) * (x + y)
return z + d[a]
```

Might an optimizing compiler effectively change the last line to `return z + x`?

If so, is this optimization invalid in the presence of multiple threads? While this thread is calculating the value of `z`, what happens if another thread changes the value (or even the type) of `d[a]`?

Comment: Yes.  Having another thread modify the value without providing the necessary synchronization is UB.

Comment: Languages that support threading directly (rather than as an add-on) must define the entire semantics here. Languages that have it as an add-on typically provide some sort of add-on synchronization or barrier operations, and then must provide a way to make sure a compiler does not make invalid optimizations. Consider, e.g., languages that provide thread-local storage (where you could declare that d itself, and perhaps all of d's stored items, are thread-local and therefore the optimization is valid).

Comment: There is no meaningful answer that can be provided as long as this question is tagged [language-agnostic]. It is the definition of "too broad". Each language has a different specification that could or could not account for this, and therefore each language will allow an optimizer to do different things.

Answer (score 0):

The question merges multiple ones.

1 : Threads

Are created at runtime. Hence the compiler may not know how many threads are present. They assume that multiple threads may be present any time. Hence the set of optimizations is not affected by the number of threads at the program level. But yes, it is affected at the compiler level. The compiler must count with the threat of data race. At least for older programming languages. In modern programming language technology this problem is dealt with strength of static type system [see [Rust]](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/races.html)  and [functional purity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional_programming).

2 : The kind of optimization you concretely mention looks difficult even in the ensured absence of threading. In its full generality ["non-trivial indexing"] : it requires the optimizer to recognize equality between expressions. I suspect this is not done in most of the compilers because of its running time requirement.

Comment: *"Hence the compiler may not know how many threads are present."* How could that possibly be true? It is the compiler that generates code to create the threads, thus it certainly knows how many there are. *"The kind of optimization…looks difficult...it requires the optimizer to recognize equality between expressions."* Uhh, C and C++ compilers regularly perform optimizations like this. It isn't as difficult as you make it out to be, not once you've inlined boilerplate code and collapsed everything down into an abstract syntax tree.

Comment: @[Cody Gray] The compiler (at least, a C/C++ compiler - don't know about JIT compilers) can't tell the number of running threads since this is known only at runtime.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, @valiano. The compiler has to emit code that starts the threads, so it knows exactly how many threads have been started. Are you perhaps talking about threads in *different applications*? If so, I can't see how that has anything to do with this question.

Comment: @[Cody Gray] The Compiler emits code for one function at a time, leave inlining aside. Even had it knew the number of threads started in some function, it can't use this information for compiling other functions (and even if it could, functions could be compiled in different times, reside in different libs, ...). All the compiler does for threading is to generate assembly code to comply with your threading and syncrhonization C/C++ code - it doesn't add any "wisdom" of its own in that sense.

Comment: @CodyGray, different branches of the program are executed for different inputs. On different branches the number of threads may be different.

Comment: Common sub-expression elimination would allow the second use of d[a] to be replaced with the value yielded by the first unless one of the variables that was changed has the same type as d[a] *and* has its address taken or exposed to outside code.  CSE is a relatively safe but effective optimization if compilers cautiously re-evaluate expressions in cases where there's any *particular* reason to believe the value might be disturbed.